# php/mysql table row progressive number

Tags: php, html, do-while

I have a table with data taken from the database. the query is `select * from mytable`.
the table is constructed with `<table>...<tr> ....... </tr> ... </table>`.
The data in the table are loaded via a `do while` loop.
I need to add a column containing a progressive number for each line, but I do not know how to do the `do while` loop.
How can I do?
thank you

Comment: add a var `$cnt=0` before the loop. echo it's value inside the loop, increase with `$cnt++;` at the end (but inside) the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a variable to hold your number. Start it at zero and increment it on each loop:

```
$num = 0;
do {
   $num++; //increment $num
   echo '<td>'.$num.'</td>';
} while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
```

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: ...and if the query is set to "... LIMIT .." for paginate.. how t do?